# Drawing a custom mouse cursor

Tags: c++, windows

I am in need of drawing a custom mouse cursor using C++ for my application. I am using a device to track hand movements and translate them into a cursor position on the screen.

However, for this application the system cursor may or may not be displayed, so I need to somehow draw onto the screen. I also need to interact with any window. Because of this, I'm not sure of my course of action - I believe I can create a "transparent" window to draw on while passing clicks/drags through onto the next window but am not sure how to go about this.

EDIT: Clarification - This application might be run on a touchscreen device where the cursor is hidden by some means. I'm trying my best to create this application as "hands-off" of the host system as possible - this program is meant to be a drag and drop application that will just work on a system with none or very very minimal actions done to the settings of the host system itself.

Currently, I have the following which draws a cursor at the location of the "mouse" but I cannot figure out how to refresh the screen or draw over the old "cursor" before drawing the new one. This causes a repeated cursor across the screen:

```
// Some thread
DWORD WINAPI Cursor(LPVOID lpParam) {
  auto dc = GetDC(NULL);
  std::optional<POINT> point;
  while (true) {
    if (point.has_value()) {
      auto p = point.value();
      RoundRect(......); // Paint over old cursor
    }

    POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(&p)) {
      point.emplace(p);
      RoundRect(......); // Paint new cursor
  }
}
```

I've read that simply calling another RoundRect on the same location will clear it but that's obviously not the case or I'm doing it wrong.

I believe my program can have super privileges if it needs to. Working with WINAPI seems to be kind of a hassle compared to this kind of stuff on linux, regarding permissions of working with different windows and allowing clicks and such to go through....

Any suggestions for how to proceed?

Comment: IMHO, you should not be drawing a cursor manually - you can use a custom cursor resource using standard means. `the system cursor may or may not be displayed` - can you elaborate what you mean by this?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The system this application could be running on is a touchscreen where the cursor could possibly be hidden from view from the user. I'm not sure if or how this could affect using a custom cursor resource instead of painting directly onto the screen.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Updated OP with a better explanation